# Sudoers still asks for password while executing the bash script

Tags: linux, sudo

When I try to execute a bash script which has sudo access set in sudoers file but it still asks for password

**sudoers_dev** file in `/etc/sudoers.d/sudoers_dev`

```
Cmnd_Alias DEPLOYER       =     /home/deployer/test.sh
%dev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: DEPLOYER
```

I (username: aj) was part of the dev group and the file `test.sh` permissions are set as

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 deployer deployer  2122 Jun 23 13:00 test.sh
```

**Commands:**

```
[aj@centos ~]$ sudo -u deployer  /home/deployer/test.sh
```

OR

```
ssh aj@centos sudo -u delpoyer /home/deployer/test.sh
```

**Errors:** When running from the aj@centos machine

```
It asks for deployer password
```

When running from an other terminal

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Comment: Is there a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` that applies different flags to the `%dev` group?  Or perhaps a line farther down in the `/etc/sudoers.conf` file?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 other files in `/etc/sudoers.d` which has flags to the `%dev` group

Comment: Most sudo installations import the files in `/etc/sudoers.d` at the end of the `/etc/sudoers.conf` file.  This means settings in those files can/will override conflicting settings that appeared earlier in the `sudoers.conf` file.  Perhaps add your `DEPLOYER` reference to one of those files rather than creating a line for it in `sudoers.conf`

Comment: I didnt add a line in `sudoers.conf` file rather I added a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d` dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user **aj** is in group **dev** just:

`$ sudo /home/deployer/test.sh`

No need of `sudo -u deployer ...`. But if you really need to run as user **deployer**, are you sure **deployer** is in group **dev**?